# Need to create root account?

Tags: root

Do we need to create a root account in addition to a user account? I am the only person to use the system on my Thinkpad.

Comment: Clue: When you installed Ubuntu, were you prompted to create a root login?

Answer (score 2):

No.

root is already a user in Ubuntu that is created so you can still do tasks that require global changes. The account you created Ubuntu with is a normal user with elevated privileges to make it a user that can do root tasks.

In 99.99% of the things you need to do you do not require root. In cases you do just type

```
sudo -i
```

and provide your password and you are a root use. Be ware: even if you are a single user keeping root active when you walk away of your system lets anyone do anything to your system; like erasing the disk, install software to track you, encrypting your disk.

You can use root to reset passwords for instance but can also do that from a live session or grub resque.

Example:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for rinzwind: 
root@schijfwereld:~#
```